# Selection.Paste not keeping complete source formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that copies from a small word document to a main word document, inserting at a bookmark. The content that is copies is within a table and has various rows and columns containing data and a few images.

My code is as follows:

```
Set SmallDoc = Documents.Open("small.doc")
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy

'Paste document content at bookmark
Set MasterDoc = Documents.Open("main.doc")
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="placeToPaste"
Selection.Paste
```

**Issue:**

The formatting is mostly kept, except the images transfer across and look as though they are cut off. Is there a way to keep the entire source formatting or some way to fix this issue?

Comment: I know that copy-pasting into Word manually can cause similar issues. Are you able to reproduce these steps without using a macro? What are your results from that?

Comment: It is the same, but I can just click the little paste options popup in the corner and select 'Keep source formatting', which fixes it. Can't do this via macros apparently, oh well. 

A little hack fix I did to fix some of the issues was to make all images in the source document to square wrapping (see answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't seem to find if it's possible to ensure source formatting is kept, in my particular case this was helpful in keeping the images displaying correctly:

```
'Opens and selects the current document
Dim CurrentDoc As Document
Set CurrentDoc = Documents.Open('c:/your/file/here.doc')
CurrentDoc.Select

'Cycle each image and change its formatting
For Each Pic In Selection.InlineShapes
    Pic.ConvertToShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
```

It has worked for me when copying a TextBox (drawing) and a jpeg along with text.